# Совпадение элементов jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть класс `item`, с `data-id="integer"`, как с помощью jquery сделать алерт, если на странице появились 2 или более блока с одинаковым числом в `data-id`? Мне это нужно для дебага.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно решить так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ids = $('.item').map(function(){ return $(this).attr('data-id'); }).get();
  if (ids.length) {
    var id_counts = {};
    $(ids).each(function() {
      id_counts[this] = id_counts[this] + 1 || 1;
    });
    $.each(id_counts, function(key, value) {
      if (value > 1) {
        alert('.item with data-id=' + key + ' duplicates ' + value + ' times.');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="item" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="item" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="item" data-id="4"></div>
<div class="item" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="item" data-id="4"></div>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/gunL2sjh/)

Comment: Только подозреваю что мутирующий тоже надо проверять - DOMNodeInserted